# Custom React Hook typescript error on array return type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-scripts

I've created a very simple custom hook:

```
export function useI18n() : [ string, Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>> ] {
  const [ language, setLanguage ] = useState<string>(i18n.language)

  useEffect(() => {
    i18n.changeLanguage(language)
  }, [ language ])

  return [ language,  setLanguage ];
}
```

And in my components I use this hook like this:

```
const [language, setLanguage] = useI18n();
```

I'm using react-scripts, and when I do `npm start` I get the following:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/config/i18n.ts
  Line 0:  Parsing error: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

However this **error doesn't happen** if I setup my hook to return an Object instead of an Array, like this:

```
export function useI18n() : { language: string, setLanguage: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>> } {
  const [ language, setLanguage ] = useState<string>(i18n.language)

  useEffect(() => {
    i18n.changeLanguage(language)
  }, [ language ])

  return { language,  setLanguage };
```

in which case I call it like this:

```
const { language, setLanguage } = useI18n();
```

Anybody understand why returning the array causes a compilation failure? Maybe I'm making some strange mistake.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know why this would be an error and I [can't reproduce it](https://tsplay.dev/rNdXnN).  Where is the `map` statement that is throwing the error?  I can't see why you would be mapping anything here.

Comment: There is no map, it's something internal to react. The fact that the error happens in "Line 0" is also a giveway of something weird.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem, I got advice from another programmer to add `as const` for `return`

```
 return [language, setLanguage] as const
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).